# sqlalchemy exception mysql is returning version as tuple instead of string

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a very confusing problem with sqlalchemy. This isn't the first time I've used sqlalchemy. I'm working on a new project we just stood up from scratch, so it is possible there is a configuration error. I include the python connector package below from our pip reqs file in case it is of interest:

```
mysql-connector-repackaged==0.3.1
```

I just created a basic unit test to evaluate our sql wrapper class. The method under evaluation is an add_user class, which simply adds a user to the database. The class first runs a query to see if the user exists. This query is not succeeding.

Here is the code for the query:

```
q = self.session.query(User).\
   filter_by(name=name, email=email)
result = q.all()
```

Seems simple enough, right? I'll include my connection string below in case anyone is interested:

```
db =create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(user=conn.USER, password=conn.PASS, host=conn.HOST, port=conn.PORT, database=database, poolclass=NullPool))
```

The database is empty, although the table structure does exist. When this query is run it throws an exception. The exception reads as below:

```
StatementError: expected string or buffer (original cause: TypeError: expected string or buffer) u"SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'" []
```

This exception comes from the python regular expression class `re.py`. The end of the stack trace looks like this:

```
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
```

If I break on that line I can see the problem. The string object which the _compile method is running is not a string at all. It is a tuple. The tuple looks like this: `(0, 3, 1, '', '')`

Now, while it is obvious why that method is breaking, it is not at all obvious why a tuple is being passed in to that method. All of that happens internally to third party libraries. I include the full stack trace below for reference:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/test/databasetest.py", line 14, in setUp
    userId = self.add_user(Constants.TestObjects.USER_ID, Constants.TestObjects.USER_EMAIL, Constants.TestObjects.USER_PHONE)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/test/databasetest.py", line 27, in add_user
    result = q.all()
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2320, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2438, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2451, in _execute_and_instances
    close_with_result=True)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2442, in _connection_from_session
    **kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 854, in connection
    close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 858, in _connection_for_bind
    return self.transaction._connection_for_bind(engine)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 322, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind.contextual_connect()
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1798, in contextual_connect
    self.pool.connect(),
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 338, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 644, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 440, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 963, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 285, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 416, in __init__
    exec_once(self.connection, self)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 250, in exec_once
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 260, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1219, in go
    return once_fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 166, in first_connect
    dialect.initialize(c)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2453, in initialize
    self._detect_ansiquotes(connection)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2718, in _detect_ansiquotes
    connection.execute("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'"),
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 721, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 870, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 893, in _execute_context
    None, None)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1159, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 889, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 635, in _init_statement
    if not dialect.supports_unicode_statements and \
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 725, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqlconnector.py", line 97, in supports_unicode_statements
    return util.py3k or self._mysqlconnector_version_info > (2, 0)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 725, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqlconnector.py", line 131, in _mysqlconnector_version_info
    self.dbapi.__version__)
  File "/home/vagrant/GitRepos/SqlInteraction/venv/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
StatementError: expected string or buffer (original cause: TypeError: expected string or buffer) u"SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'" []
```

I have no idea why this problem is occurring. I've bounced around the net with no useful results. I'm hoping someone here at SO might have some idea what is going on.

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: The latest version of mysql-connector seems to be 2.0.2 (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) Are you using version 0.3.1? It's possible that version is too old and the API it provides isn't compatible with SQLAlchemy. Have you (can you?) try a newer version to check that?

Comment: This was the problem. I didn't even consider it, because we have other applications with (what I thought were) the same configuration.

I was unable to directly update the package. I had to fully destroy and rebuild the venv. the following pip comment worked to install the newer version:

pip install http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.2.zip#md5=fc07f0309d1545317d82c49593548d7f

Comment: If only all problems were that easy to fix :-)